# In ggplot2, reorder not working as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below df:

```
prod <- c('apple', 'avocado', 'banana', 'papaya', 'pine')
year <- c(2016, 2017)
qty <- c(20, 5, 10, 1, 15, 30, 7, 15, 1, 20)

prod_yr <- data.frame('prod'= rep(prod, 2), 'yr'= c(rep(2016, 5), rep(2017, 5)), 'qty'= qty)
```

I want to see the result as a bar chart, so I use ggplot's `geom_bar` functionality. Now,I want to see the bars ordered in descending order per year. Hence, I do:

```
ggplot(data = prod_yr, aes(x = reorder(yr, -qty),
                                y = qty, 
                                fill = prod)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

This actually orders the bars in descending order from 2017 - 2016 while the `prod` is ordered alphabetically. But I want to see the bars ordered in descending order as per `qty`. So, for 2016/2017, the expected output of bars is in descending order of their quantity *i.e.* apple (20), pine (15), banana (10), avocado (5), papaya (1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reorder the `fill` component by `-qty`:

```r
ggplot(data = prod_yr, 
       aes(x = factor(yr), y = qty, fill = reorder(prod, -qty))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Quantity", fill = "Product")
```

[image]

Comment: this works, even with ```x = yr```. Can you please explain what ```reorder``` does when placed in ```x``` vs. ```fill```?

Comment: @Kay You only have two x values on your plot: 2016 and 2017. The bars are _dodged_ at each x value according to their fill colour, meaning that they are separated out on the x axis so you can see the 5 different bars, but are still notionally all at the same x value. Remember, it is your `prod` that you want ordered, not the years, so you order the `prod`, not the years.